# No output from Minibian on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've been trying to run Minibian on my Raspberry Pi but can't seem to get it to work. The screen simply receives no input, so to be fair, it might not run at all.

I have no problem using Raspbian but have the same problem with Moebian. So far I've been uncompressing using ether 7-zip on Windows or tar on Linux and writing it using Win32 Disk Imager.

My Raspberry is a B+ model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It dosen't seem to have been updated in the last year](http://minibianpi.wordpress.com/), so your packages are too old to support B+ I guess.

I'd suggest trying a different distro, or loading the SD card on a Model B, and running apt-get update

Comment: Some more research later I can conclude that you're right. And unfortunately I don't have a B model. So I guess I'll have to wait for the author to release an update (which he at least has promised to do)